# Проблема в запуске Django и получения ответа не в консоль Pycharm а в CMD

Tags: python, django

Я начал изучать Django и работать я начал на Pycharm Professional. При запуске сервера или при попытке миграции вместо того чтобы увидеть вывод данных в консоль Pycharm, это все происходит в cmd и cmd сразу закрывается, т.е я даже не вижу ошибок или даже локального адреса сервера. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой или просто знает как ее исправить помогите пожалуйста. Не хочу застрять надолго из-за такой проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Напишите слово `python` перед командой.

Например: `python manage.py makemigrations`. Должно помочь.

Comment: Добавлю, что для запуска сервера вы можете настроить конфиг (см. меню в правом верхнем углу IDE). Это будет просто удобнее, чем каждый раз прописывать команду запуска вручную.

Comment: спасибо большое